# Iterate through a sorted nested dictionary in python

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I'm facing troubles to iterate through a sorted nested dictionary. By nested dictionary, I mean a dictionary that contains other dictionaries like this :

```
{"A": 
    {"subA": {"Date": ["date1", "date2"],
              "numDownloads": [int1, int2]}
     "subB": {"Date": ["date3", "date4"],
              "numDownloads": [int3, int4]}
    }
 "B":
    {"subC": {"Date": ["date5", "date6"],
              "numDownloads": [int5, int6]}
     "subD": {"Date": ["date7", "date8"],
              "numDownloads": [int7, int8]}
    }
}
```

I would like to iterate for each first-level keys (A and B in this case) on the second-level keys (subA, subB for A and subC, subD for B) sorted by the first value of numDownloads ascending (int1, int 3 for A and int 5, int 7 for B).

If I give an example of what I want : 
Consider this dictionnary :

```
{"A": 
    {"subA": {"Date": ["date1", "date2"],
              "numDownloads": [100, 500]}
     "subB": {"Date": ["date3", "date4"],
              "numDownloads": [500, 1000]}
    }
 "B":
    {"subC": {"Date": ["date5", "date6"],
              "numDownloads": [10000, 50000]}
     "subD": {"Date": ["date7", "date8"],
              "numDownloads": [500, 1000]}
    }
}
```

I would like to iterate though A with subA then subB as subA first numDownloads value (100) is lower than subB first numDownloads value (500) and though B with subD then subC and subC first numDownloads value (10000) is greater than subD first numDownloads value (500).

I tried with the [sorted()](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/sorted) function and a lambda expression but I can't make it work for my case.

```
for firstKey in myDict:
    firstKeyData = myDict[firstKey]
    for key in sorted(firstKeyData, key=lambda k: firstKeyData[k]["numDownloads"][0]):
        // here, sub keys are sorted according to the first element of numDownloads 
        // A : subA then subB
        // B : subD then subC
```

Here is the example of the json file :

```
{
   "Social":{
      "Facebook":{
         "Date":[
            "2019-02-19"
         ],
         "numDownloads":[
            "100000000"
         ]
      },
      "Twitter":{
         "Date":[
            "2019-02-19"
         ],
         "numDownloads":[
            "100000"
         ]
      }
   },
   "Instagram":{
      "Date":[
         "2019-02-19"
      ],
      "numDownloads":[
         "5000"
      ]
   },
   "Communication":{
      "Messenger":{
         "Date":[
            "2019-02-19"
         ],
         "numDownloads":[
            "100000"
         ]
      },
      "Whatsapp":{
         "Date":[
            "2019-02-19"
         ],
         "numDownloads":[
            "50000000"
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Thanks for all

Comment: Your code works just fine. Please be specific about what is not working for you if you think it isn't.

Comment: Should subdicts be reordered globally or only within their own top-level dict? That is, if `subD` had `"numDownloads": [400, 1000]`, would it have to go before `subB`.  If not (that is, if subdicts are only sorted within their group), what would be the criterion to iterate top-level dicts (key string, smallest `numDownloads` value among all subdicts, ...)?

Comment: @blhsing : The sorting is not working for some items I don't know why. For example, some sub-dicts with 5000 numDownloads appears after other sub-dicts with 10000 numDownloads and it's messing my sorting

Comment: @jdehesa : subdicts need to be reorder on their own top-level. In my example, I need to reorder `subA` and `subB` under `A` and `subC` and `subD` under `B`

Comment: @Maxouille But then how do you decide whether you start with `A` or `B`? Is it just lexicographic order? Or that doesn't matter?

Comment: First level keys order doesn't matter. It's just lexicographic in my example.

Comment: Can you provide a sample `dict` that replicates the problem? Because as @blhsing mentions, your code should work.  Are the `numDownloads` of mixed types (`int`, `str`, etc)?

Comment: I added a concrete example.

Comment: It's best if you just post your example within the question itself, preferably short enough to prove the point.  For instance your link is blocked for me due to network policy, and wouldn't be able to help you.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't thought about it. The Json is included inside my post :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `numDownloads` keys of your actual JSON file contain strings, rather than integers as suggested by the simplified version of your sample data, so comparisons are made lexicographically rather than numerically when you make that the returning value of your key function for sorting, so `"20"` would be considered "greater" than `"100"` as a result, for example.

You should convert the referenced items to integers instead:

```
for key in sorted(firstKeyData, key=lambda k: int(firstKeyData[k]["numDownloads"][0])):
```

Comment: Thanks ! Seems logic, I don't know why I didn't see that before :)